# Laravel Eloquent belongs to many through

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables:

- users (id, name)
- tasks (id, title)
- task_user (id, task_id, user_id, user_post_id)
- user_posts (id, title)

What I am trying to do is to fetch all users that are related to the project.

In Task model I have:

```
class Task extends \Eloquent {


    protected $guarded = [];


    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\User')->withPivot('user_post_id', 'hours');
    }


}
```

And is is working pretty well. I am getting this result:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [id] => 9
    [created_at] => 1996-08-04 08:35:59
    [updated_at] => 1991-07-27 16:36:47
    [username] => xcremin
    [email] => amely.wunsch@gmail.com
    [remember_token] => $2y$10$WmtDoCCIA25Z/CF28KqlwOngR5vHvghD3cu0bbtPGftUV/ez2WBGe
    [pivot] => Array
        (
            [task_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 9
            [user_post_id] => 10
        )

)
```

Here you can see pivot `user_post_id` field. The question is - how could i fetch the title of that field (with user_post_id = 10)?

Comment: You would have to create a relationship in users for `user_posts`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add relation in your TaskUser class

```
public function userPost()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('UserPost');
    }
```

and after you''ll be able to get the name by doing something like in your view

```
 @foreach($task->users as $user)
        {{ $user->pivot->userPost->title }}
  @foreach
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$user_posts = DB::table("user_post")
                ->whereIn("user_post_id", array($user_post_id))
                ->get();
```